# CSS backdrop-filter much slower on chrome than -webkit-backdrop-filter is on safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-filters

I am applying a backdrop filter to a navigation menu on my site. To support multiple browsers, I include both `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px) brightness(65%);` and `backdrop-filter: blur(3px) brightness(65%)` in the css for that div. I get extreme framerate drops when using the site in google chrome and opening that navigation menu; however, safari has no framerate drops whatsoever. Why might this be? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You might have hardware acceleration disabled. I had the same issue and it's much quicker now that I enabled it.

Go to Chrome://settings on the URL bar, then turn on "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Image

[hardware acceleration chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyOvQ.png)